# The reCAPTCHA sometime appear sometime doesn't. Used https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions to configure

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, recaptcha

We are using https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions to configure reCAPTCHA in our Angular project. The issue is, reCAPTCHA sometime shows sometime doesn't.
I have included the script in my index.html

and sitekey in the app-component.html

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/losHr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOzHv.png)

Tried to include the reCAPTCHA but it sometime shows up and sometime  doesn't.